# To do some operation with .docx by using python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, filepath, docx, glob

I have created a script for getting the path name from user and do some .docx operations. When i run the script it is giving the total number of .docx in that folder but it doesn't work for the table counting. I don't know that I'm using correct code with **tkinter**. I have tried the **pathlib** and **os.path** but it doesn't work.

here is my code:

```
    import os
    import glob
    import os.path
    from docx import Document

    from tkinter import *
    def print_input():

#To print how many files with .docx extension in the folder 

        mypath = text_entry.get()
        files=0
        for name in os.listdir(mypath):
            if name.endswith('.docx'):
              files=files+1
        print("Total No of Files:",files)

        #To read the .docx and print how many tables in that 

        table=0
        for name in glob.glob('/*.docx'):
          doc=Document(name)
          for t in doc.tables:
            for ro in t.rows:
             if ro.cells[0].text=="ID" :
                table=table+1
          print("Total Number of Tables: ", table)

    root = Tk()
    Label(root, text="Enter Path").grid(row=0)

    text_entry = Entry(root)
    text_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
    text_entry.config(background="yellow", foreground="blue")
    Button(root, text='Submit', command=print_input).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
    mainloop()
```

When I try to specify the path name inside the glob it is working but when i try to pass the value from the textbox it is not executing instead of giving correct details it shows random numbers. Hope you understand my problem

Comment: `for name in glob.glob(mypath+'/*.docx'):` should work too

Comment: can you give an example of the random numbers it is showing?

Comment: @PRMoureu you save my day. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Don't have any idea what "doesn't work" means, but you are getting names from "mypath"

```
for name in os.listdir(mypath):
```

but tables are coming from '/*.docx'

```
for name in glob.glob('/*.docx'):
```

Do it in one operation (and take a look at filedialog.askdirectory)

```
    mypath = text_entry.get()
    files=0
    for name in os.listdir(mypath):
        if name.endswith('.docx'):
          files=files+1
    #print("Total No of Files:",files)

    #To read the .docx and print how many tables in that 

          table=0
    ##for name in glob.glob('/*.docx'):
          doc=Document(name)
          for t in doc.tables:
              for ro in t.rows:
                  if ro.cells[0].text=="ID" :
                      table=table+1
```

Comment: When I try make it as a one operation I found the error:                                         "Package not found at '%s'" % pkg_file
docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'third.docx'

Comment: can you please edit the full code of your's? @Curly Joe

Comment: Again, I don't know what "When I try make it as a one operation I found the error:" means or what line it refers to.  You probably have to provide the complete path to the file so os.path.join(mypath, name) to Document().  Print it also to make sure it is going where you want to go.